# Calculate the difference power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am struggling to calculate the difference in power BI.
I made a measure to calculate total feedback, and I show the feedback by category, now I would like to display the difference between the total amount of august - total amount in July for a specific category.

So, for example, if you pick the month August, you should see the total for August, and next to it difference column shows what was the difference between July and August.

[image]

My measure for total is

```
totalCount = DIVIDE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('prediction'), 'prediction'[sentiment]= "POS"), COUNT('prediction'[sentiment])
```

Comment: You haven't used the reference of Month anywhere in the formula. Its unclear how your data is structured

Comment: I updated my question, maybe now it is more clear what I am having an issue with.